# How to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

I know that this code generates a error in Eclipse, but how do I catch it before it puts out

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at ArgsContentCopier.main(ArgsContentCopier.java:13)
```

I want to catch it and then throw a string. Instead of saying the exception in thread... I want it to say for example, "Two args required."

---

Thanks for the help, I figured it out!

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
   This program copies content of a file into another.
*/
public class ArgsContentCopier
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
      if(args.length != 2) //if args array != 2 then print error
      {
            System.out.println("Error: Two args required");
      }
      else{

          String one = args[0];
          String two = args[1];
          String inFile;
          String outFile;
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            try
            {  


                //System.out.print("Input file: ");
                    inFile = one;
                //System.out.print("Output file: ");
                    outFile = two;

                        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
                        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

                        byte[] b = new byte[1024]; //this line reads a new byte into b from 0 to 1024bytes.
                        int len; //keeps track of the len (up to the # of bytes to read)
                        while((len = inStream.read(b)) != -1) //if there is nothing else to read, returns -1
                        {
                            outStream.write(b, 0, len); //read the docs on this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29
                        }

                        inStream.close();
                        outStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {  
                System.out.println("Error processing file: " + exception);
            }     


        }
}
}
```

Comment: Check if args.length > 0;

Comment: You cannot `throw a string`.

Comment: To catch it, is to prevent it from ever being thrown.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Be nice, the "string" he's referring to is the exception cause. It's not like he's trying to do `throw "Two args required"` directly.

Comment: Replace `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Two ars requiered.");` with your error message, e.g. `System.out.println("Two ars requiered.");`.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` are meant to prevent the use of an invalid index: `Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.` I believe you might use another exception that fits better.. `IllegalArgumentException` perhaps?

Comment: If you want just to display message, then just check the number of parameters (args.length) and print it.  While you can create custom exception, it makes sense only to be caught and interpreted by  a method higher in the *calling tree*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to catch it if you don't let it be thrown.  Check the array length before you access the array to ensure that the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` won't be thrown.

```
if (args.length != 2)
{
    System.out.println("Two args required.");
    return;
}
// Now access args[0] and args[1]
```

Comment: And indeed you should *never* be catching that exception.

Comment: Also this should be at the start of the main method or `String one = args[0];` these would throw the error anyway